# Invalid input syntax for timestamp error with Postgres Copy command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to load data in Postgres through `COPY` command in a SQL file

```
COPY <table name>  (<column1>, <column2>, <column3> etc etc) FROM stdin;

1    test1   test2   to_timestamp(1592818988000)
```

But I am getting this below error:

> psql:/Users/sanupin/load.sql:1045: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for
> type timestamp: "to_timestamp(1641278614000)" CONTEXT:  COPY
> cstone_storage, line 1, column last_loaded:
> "to_timestamp(1641278614000)"

Any idea what could be the problem? I know I have to convert the millisecond to second (div by 1000) on the epoch number, but not sure how else to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` does not evaluate expressions. It takes data only. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> `COPY` moves data between PostgreSQL tables and standard file-system files.

(With the exception of an optional `WHERE` clause added with Postgres 12.)

To evaluate expressions, use `INSERT`.

I suggest to `COPY` to a temporary staging table - with a `double precision` column for the yet unconverted timestamp - and `INSERT` from there. See:

- [COPY command: copy only specific columns from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708171/939860)
- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910810/939860)